# it is possible to consider the uncertainties of labels when training CNNs for image object recognition

Tags: deep-learning, annotations, conv-neural-network, supervised-learning

I have automatically created a data set for object detection for camera images. However, the algorithm I use for this makes mistakes. But I can calculate the uncertainty

*Now my question: Is it possible to consider these uncertainties when training a neural net? If so, how? Has one of you ever read a paper about it?*

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about it myself. (Maybe I just use the wrong keywords in my search)

First of all, thank you very much for your help!

ps: A few details: I got a robot with a lidar who is calculating his posision of an object with a common slam-algorithm. I can calculate the covriance matrix for the position. I use these information to create the label for the 2d image. Later on I'd like to use a cheap camera to do the same job as the lidar

Answer (score 0):

if I get your question right, it is about a noisy training data set? 
If so, there are some paper available which address this problem - e.g.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.03419.pdf

or

https://jingdongwang2017.github.io/Pubs/CVPR16-DisturbLabel.pdf

Hope those papers are a little helpful :)